# How to use CACHE or PERSIST with explicit storage level in SQL mode (not Dataset API)?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How to use `PERSIST` with storage level in SQL mode in Spark SQL? One can use `CACHE` in in Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL mode, as executed using `spark-sql` or `spark.sql`, only `CACHE` statement is available as described in Spark SQL's [ANTLR grammar](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L159):

> CACHE LAZY? TABLE tableIdentifier (AS? query)?

`PERSIST` or `CACHE` with a persistent storage level do not appear in the grammar which is the definitive list of what the Spark SQL parser allows for.